# How to Bind a Dictionary with the Key value being a Binding Property in WPF?

Tags: wpf, data-binding, wpfdatagrid

I have a class like this:

```
public class Person
{
    public int PersonId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int AccountId { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<int, List<string>> Values { get; set; }
}
```

I have a `DataGrid` in my XAML where I want to display the first index of the `List<string>` within the dictionary property **Values** as one of the column values, where the key being passed in will be the **AccountId**.  The `ItemSource` of my `DataGrid` is a list of Person objects coming from my ViewModel, and the `DataGrid` has 3 columns, **PersonId**, **Name**, and **Value** (where value is the first index of the `List<string>` collection in the dictionary item)

I have seen examples on stackoverflow and other places on the internet that try to do this but none of the solutions worked for me.

Here is my XAML code:

```
<DataGrid Name="MyDataGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding Persons}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="ID">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding PersonId}" IsEnabled="False" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Name">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding Name}" IsEnabled="False" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Value">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding Values[{Binding AccountId}][0]}" IsEnabled="False" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

The last column is the column where I try to use a `{Binding}` as the key value, but it does not work.  If I hard-code a valid **AccountId**, it works.  Has anyone encountered this before?

Thanks!

Comment: Write a multi-value converter. You can index a collection in a binding path, but only ever with a constant value.

Comment: Thanks!  Was reading that that is the way to go, wondering if WPF had a way of doing this without using a converter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one of view model purposes is to provide data to view in a convenient format. code to get value from dictionary by key and then return first item can be written in a view model, not in converter:

```
public class Person
{
    public int PersonId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int AccountId { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<int, List<string>> Values { get; set; }

    public string AccountIdValue { get { return Values[AccountId].FirstOrDefault(); } }
}
```

then bind to that helper property:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding AccountIdValue}" IsEnabled="False" />
```